# Why aren't my custom routes in django recognized?

Tags: python, django, routes, rendering, crud

I'm trying this Django tutorial
https://www.javatpoint.com/django-crud-application

Here is how my view is defined:

```
def show(request):
    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    return render(request, "show.html", {'employees': employees})
```

Here is how my url file in the django_crud project (my project name) is defined:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from employee import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('emp', views.emp),
    path('show', views.show),
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit),
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),
]
```

My templates are in employee/templates
My app is obviously registered:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'employee'
]
```

I run the server with python manage.py runserver with no errors.
Migrations are done with no error.
The database is empty, but this should not matter.

The problem is that only the admin route work. The show route (or any other) doesn't work.

I hate when a tutorial doesn't work and I'm triying to figure out the problem, but I don't see any issue. Maybe the turorial is about an old version of Django and I have something missing? Any insight?

Comment: It is better to use a separate urls.py for the app. And include the app in project's urls.py.

Comment: What is value of `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings? Also end all your urls with `/` unless you set `APPEND_SLASH = False` (best not to do just end your urls in slashes) in your settings.

Comment: For beginner, you'd better follow this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_crud.urls'
Putting / at the end doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Problem solved. I had a second urlpatterns array with only admin route. It seems that this overwrote my routes.

Comment: Would highly recommend using the official django tutorial so you know you're starting things off right. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/